# 2001 Malibu air conditioner won't stay on

Tags: chevrolet, ac, malibu, compressor

When I turn on the AC, I can see the compressor clutch engage, blower motor is running, no cool air. I also noticed about every 5 seconds a light 'clunk' from the area of the compressor. After about 15 seconds, the AC light turns off. Sometimes the AC light will go on and off.

I started to add a can of freon but noticed the pressure was pretty high, so I stopped.

Am I looking at a bad compressor?

Answer (score 1):

Observing the compressor clutch engage and most likely disengagement with zero cooling are indications of a loss of refrigerant. There's just enough left to cycle the compressor but not enough to cool the interior. You have a leak somewhere and refilling is just adding refrigerant to.............a leaking system. Observing a jump in pressure from the refill canister gauge also shows you're unfamiliar with vehicle ac system operating pressures and what occurs when attempting to refill a system. The best advice for anyone unfamiliar and not willing to learn about ac systems is refraining from throwing away money on refill kits and buy and use an inexpensive uv blacklight to search for dye. GM installs dye at factory ac assembly to make it easier for dealers, repair shops and knowledgeable diyers to find leaks using a uv light in darkness. Dye glows from a uv blacklight to show where damage occurred.
If you spend the money on a uv blacklight and take the time to shine it all over the ac system parts and find the source of the leak(s), then an only then will you be able to determine whether or not replacing parts are possible and following up with using  an electric vacuum pump and gauges or leave this part to a repair shop to save on costs.
A uv light should be the first tool to use, not a refill kit. And your compressor is fine, not broken, yet.